# How to get Array data when using Firebase Realtime Database in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm in a trouble when I get data from Firebase Realtime Database so I write this question.

Here is the thing what I wanna do.

This is data saved in Firebase database.

```
{ "schedule": 
  {"day0" : [{"title":"wake up", "content":"Wake up at 7 AM"},
             {"title":"School","content":"Go to the school"}],
   "day1" : [{"title":"day1 wakeup", "content":"Wake up at 8 AM"},
             {"title":"Supermarket", "content" :"buy some food"}]
   }
}
```

In this case, I wanna get all the schedule in day0.

```
[{"title":"wake up", "content":"Wake up at 7 AM"},
{"title":"School","content":"Go to the school"}]
```

So I make a code like this.

```
var ref:DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("schedule").child("day0").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
  var postData = [NSDictionary]()
  self.dataList = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!
  print("\(self.dataList)")
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And this is result. :(

```
{"title":"wake up", "content":"Wake up at 7 AM"}
```

How can I get all the data in the value of "day0"?

Comment: Replace childAdded with value

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thank you for you answer! I think I'm misunderstanding about FIRDataEventType. After I chagne childAdded value to value finally I can get the value what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're observing a single `.childAdded` event. That means that you're only getting the first child node under `day0`.

There are two ways to get all children:

1. observe all `.childAdded` events
2. observe a `.value` event

The first approach is simplest...

```
ref.child("schedule").child("day0").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
  print("\((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!)")
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

With this minimal change, your completion handler will be called for each child node. Also see this [example in the documentation on listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events).

Alternatively you can observe `.value` (either once of continuously), which will be called with all matching data at once. This means that your code will need to handle the fact that it gets all data at once:

```
ref.child("schedule").child("day0").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
  var postData = [NSDictionary]()
  self.dataList = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!
  print("\(self.dataList)")
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Also see this [example in the documentation to listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataList: [Dictionary<String,Any>]?

ref.child("schedule").child("Day0").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

self.dataList = snapshot.value as! [Dictionary]
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is result what I finally success I wanna do! Thank you for your help!